# z-index and overflow not making div display correctly

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project where I am displaying messages when the user hovers over a box, I have created a scenario to mock up what I am having issues with.

The blue box should appear as the full 250px as defined and not be clipped to the 200px that the containing div is set to, is there anyway to get round this, I can sit the blue box outside the containing div as its all part of a UserControl that needs to be self contained.

```css
#first {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#second {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}

#fourth
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
    <div id="second">
      <div id="fourth">
      test
      </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `#first{ overflow: hidden }` because that is intended behavior and there is no work around apart from changing CSS/HTML structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure this is what you are after but all you need to do is change the overflow from hidden to visible on your `first` div:

```css
#first {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: visible;  /* change this */
}

#second {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}

#fourth
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
    <div id="second">
      <div id="fourth">
      test
      </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I was fully intending as I was hoping to include the scrollbar still, but there seems to be no work around apart from moving the fourth div outside the first. So I am going to see if I can try positioning the element so it works out where the edge is of the containing div and displays within the containing div

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
#first {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
```

}

To

```
#first {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: green;
```

}

In other words, remove overflow: hidden and that blue div will appear as you wanted to.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Wired said you have to remove the `overflow: hidden;` from the #first element. Otherwise all elements inside will be cut off if they should reach outside it's boundaries.

```css
#first {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

#second {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}

#fourth
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
    <div id="second">
      <div id="fourth">
      test
      </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```